# regex in swift is not working with this example?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to use Regex expressions but this does not work and I don't understand why. The `println` is not showing up in the output. I followed this [tutorial](http://benscheirman.com/2014/06/regex-in-swift/) to use this `class`:

```
class Regex {
  let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression
  let pattern: String

  init(_ pattern: String) {
    self.pattern = pattern
    var error: NSError?
    self.internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
  }

  func test(input: String) -> Bool {
    let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, countElements(input)))
    return matches.count > 0
  }
}
```

And this [other tutorial](http://www.regexr.com/) to create the Regex.

The code returns the text when I do not use Regex. If I do use it, the `println` does not appear. I tried `"(/([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)/ig)$"` and `"/([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)/ig$"` but none of them work.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        println("end editing")

        if let match = textField.text.rangeOfString("/([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)/ig$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
            println("\(match) is probably f**ked off and left as a f**king bastard")
        }

        if Regex("/([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)/ig").test(textField.text){
            println("yes")
            textField.text = textField.text.uppercaseString
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your input for `textField.text`? Could you give us some examples of what you want to match the regex, and what you don't want to match?

Comment: I get a compiler error in above `self.internalExpression =...` : not unwrapped.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian You should add a `!` at the end of the line to unwrap Optional value. See the **'Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals'** section in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) `self.internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!`

Comment: @devxoul Thx for moving it as a comment, but my comment was just meant as a comment to the OP :-) I know that I have to add `!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you do not need to use (/ ..... /ig)$, so try this:

```
   if let match = textField.text.rangeOfString("([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
                println("\(match) is bla bla bla...")
            }
```

It will be work and return the range of the first occurrence of a given string

Comment: thanks, what about case insensitive? Is there a better way than `( [a-z]+ | [A-Z]+ )`  ?

Comment: If you mean the way to find uppercase simbols, then [A-Z] is the standard choice

Comment: anyway to still use i , g , u ... flags in pattern?